# MySQLWorkbench Quit unexpectedly on macOS 12.6

Tags: mysql-workbench

---

### Translated Report (Full Report Below)

Process:               MySQLWorkbench [10215]
Path:                  /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/MacOS/MySQLWorkbench
Identifier:            com.oracle.workbench.MySQLWorkbench
Version:               8.0.29.CE (1)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        launchd [1]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2022-09-18 01:13:02.9024 +0700
OS Version:            macOS 12.6 (21G115)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        93C12037-7AA4-2F17-6953-BD95C09A967C

Time Awake Since Boot: 8100 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000008
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000008
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 11 Segmentation fault: 11
Terminating Process:   exc handler [10215]